# who to access nodejs app, in bluehost?

Tags: node.js, bluehost

I have an application running on bluehost, but I can not access this.

I've tried accessing the domain (eg *mydomain.com:8000*), but does not work.

Is there any way to access the application **without requiring a dedicated ip**?

**my app:**

```
var port = 8000;

var express = require('express'),
    gen = require('./generator');

var app = express();

app.get('/', function(request, response){
    response.send('hello word!');
});

app.use(function(err, request, response, next) {
    console.error(err.stack);
    response.send(500, 'Something broke!');
});

app.listen(port);

console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using shared hosting, and you want your application to be accessible by the general public, your best bet would be running the server on some unused IP port and writing a CGI script/binary that forwards incoming requests to the node.js server.

One of the biggest downsides to shared hosting is that you're not allowed to run your own publicly-visible servers, and node.js requires to do so in order to work.

Comment: So I'll have to buy VPS